# The Device Turning Direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion

How can I determine the device turning direction?

For example, I want to do like that

```
if ( the device turn right ) {
// do something
}

else if ( the device turn left ) {
// do something
}
```

I have done so far the following code:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(Motion) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)Motion{


#define RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))



CMDeviceMotion *currentDeviceMotion = motionManager.deviceMotion;
CMAttitude *currentAttitude = currentDeviceMotion.attitude;

float yaw = roundf((float)(RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(currentAttitude.yaw)));
 positionIn360 = yaw;
if (positionIn360 < 0)
{
    positionIn360 = 360 + positionIn360;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [CMDeviceMotion Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009942).  There are several ways to go about calculating which direction the device is turning/tilting using this framework.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want any calculation involved. because in my case I want to use if statements, how to express whether the device is turning right or left in a statement?

Comment: I haven't tried this directly, but I'd imagine you can use the CMDeviceMotion class to get a value for the rotation, then test with if statements in what direction the device is tilting based on the value.  Ie. if the value is negative, it's likely turning one direction opposed to a positive number.

Long story short, you'll have to learn to read the accelerometer, and create methods like isTiltingLeft based on the values that the accelerometer gives you.

Comment: Thank you again =). It's complicated to do it with numbers. Negative numbers don't always mean the device is turning to left or right, I could have a negative numbers while I turn the device left or right. One more thing what if the device is not turned left or right and I have a negative number? I don't know it's really blowing my mind xD